# Disable all Fonts that are Standard in WordPress and replacing them with a custom Font?

Tags: customization, css, embed, fonts

WordPress STILL loads Fonts differend from the one i defined via font-face and *{font-family}. Especially in WP-Embeds still the Font Reference

-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;

loads.
I have added a @ font-face (Raleway), which i self host, added *{font-family:Raleway) in the Customizer which seems to work on *nearly* everything but WP-Embeds. I also tried changing the WP-Embeds' Header Color (the Link Color) but that didn't work either. Has someone ANY idea on

- how to disable ALL WordPress-associated install-included Fonts and replace them with a self-hosted one?
- how to change the Font and Styling in the WP-Embed?

(It's now back to normal so you can maybe find something i missed.)

A Link to a Page i mean: https://www.gooloo.de/2022/12/jahresfavoriten-2022.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

Open your WordPress dashboard and go to the *Appearance* --> *Editor page*.

In the editor, open the `style.css` file, which is located in the right sidebar under "Stylesheets."

At the top of the `style.css` file, add a new `@font-face` rule to define your self-hosted font. The `@font-face` rule should include the font's name, the font file location, and the format. Here is an example of a `@font-face` rule for a self-hosted font called "Raleway":

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Raleway";
    src: url("/wp-content/themes/your-theme/fonts/raleway.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/wp-content/themes/your-theme/fonts/raleway.woff") format("woff");
}
```

After defining the `@font-face` rule, you can set the font-family property for all elements on your site to your self-hosted font. To do this, add the following code to the `style.css` file:

```css
* {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

Save the changes to the style.css file. Your self-hosted font should now be applied to all elements on your site.
To change the font and styling in WordPress embeds, you can try adding the following code to the `style.css` file:

```css
.wp-embed {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    /* Add other styling rules here, such as font size, color, etc. */
}
```

This will apply your self-hosted font, and any other styling rules to the WordPress embeds on your site.

Note: Make sure to replace "your-theme" with the actual name of your theme in the `@font-face` rule and the font file paths. Also, make sure that you have uploaded the font files to the correct location on your server.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or need further assistance.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I tried to do this (i use Divi, so i got to Divi > Style.css) and added the Code, but it didn't apply anything (although it was saved correctly). I also tried it in style.min.css, but that didn't work either. Here's a Screenshot: https://www.gooloo.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/scrnli_3-1-2023_22-17-15.png

Comment: I also tried replacing the fonts i found with this code: https://wp-mix.com/replace-all-instances-string-wordpress/ but that doesn't work either. Isn't there ANY way in WordPress to replace all fonts loaded by WP and Co itself and replace it with one single self-hosted font? :/

Comment: you need to add both "woff" and "woff2". and your font path doesn't seem correct. See my font path how I used it

Comment: No it's correct (https://www.gooloo.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/scrnli_4-1-2023_07-50-43.png). Fonts are at www.gooloo.de/fonts/Raleway.woff and www.gooloo.de/fonts/Raleway.woff2